# SailJs - upload upload image at client to server throught API

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, frontend

I'm working on the front end which been built on Sails JS framework.
I have a profile page, user can upload new photo of them. The avatar will send to the server throught API. But when i'm using upload function of Sails, the image just saved in the front-end folder.
Can anyone guide me how to do it? With Ajax perharps

[Update]

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input name="avatar" type="file">
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Well I did it, but maybe the worst way to do:

1. I save the upload Image to a folder of front-end
2. I resize the image(still working)
3. Finally, send the resized image throught API

This is the function implement when submit the form above

```
const UpdateProfileAvatar = (req, res) => {

    // Rename the file with new random name
    let fileName = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,5) +".jpg";

    // 2*** Save image to a folder in folder
    req.file('avatar').upload({
        maxBytes: 3*1024*1024, // limit 3MB
        saveAs: fileName,
        dirname: require('path').resolve(sails.config.appPath, 'assets/uploads')
    }, function whenDone(err, uploadedFile) {
        // 3*** Resize the image

        // 4*** Send the image throught API
        var request = require('request-promise');

        request.post({
            url: "https://api-link/user/avatar",
            formData: {
                avatar: fs.createReadStream('./assets/uploads/'+fileName)
            },
            headers: {
                token: req.session.token
            }
        })
        .then( result => {
            console.log(result);

            fs.unlinkSync('./assets/uploads/'+fileName);

            return res.redirect('/profile');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    })
```

Comment: I can't see how anyone can help you here, you have provided no code for your controller, model or view, no information on the stack you are using or even what version of sails you are running. Help others, help you.

Comment: Thanks @Glen I had updated the code